# How to copy the rows filtered by the AutoFilter() method

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2003

I've been using the AutoFilter() method with no problem so far. but I wasn't able to mark or get the range of the filtered rows, to count/copy/delete them.

I've seen many posts on this issue with VBA, but none for C#.

After filtering, I tried to get the range by any of these lines:

```
range = ws.UsedRange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing);
range = ws.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing);
range = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing);
```

And I have even tried other ways that I dont even remember.

After marking the range I tried to count the rows by doing:

```
range.Rows.Count
```

and in each case, I got the total number of lines of the sheet, sometimes I got 65536 (office 2003) and sometimes just 1 but surely not the number of rows that I filtered.

I must use it with office 2003 with Object Library 11.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. after a long sleep. i got some power to try more directions, this time without getting directions from other forums and google.

Try this:

- Apply the autoFilter on the used range of the whole workSheet

> Excel.Range range = workSheet.UsedRange;

- Apply the autoFilter on the range

> ```
>  range.AutoFilter(1, criteriaString , Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, missing, true);
> ```

(this will filter the rows according to column 1 with criteriaString as the criteria)

- Now you want to get the filtered range:

> ```
> Excel.Range filteredRange = range.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing);
> ```

- Now, you can access `filteredRange.Rows.Count` integer to count the rows, and do fun stuff.

THATS IT! it had to be simple then i ever thought it would.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For deleting the rows , it is just
    `range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);`

Comment: Author is asking for answer to copy the rows.

Answer (score 0):

after autofilter, i would like to name a term "COGI" only in range "N" in the filtered rows.how to write to just pick up that range "N" and insert a term "COGI"